# Detached entity with generated id '1' has an uninitialized version value 'null'. com.VERSION

Tags: hibernate, jpa, glassfish

When I change the hibernate version in my project, I get the error as in the title. I searched but I could not find any result.

Thank you for your help.

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>10.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
   <artifactId>jakarta.faces</artifactId>
   <version>4.0.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>6.4.3.Final</version>
   <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

I tried **6.2.0.Final, 6.3.0.Final, 6.4.0.Final** and **6.4.3.Final** versions respectively with the same result. But there is no problem with **6.1.7.Final**.

Comment: Add  relevant code and the complete stacktrace

Comment: The same is true for the entire project. It's not just about one method

Comment: which application server you are using?

Comment: GlassFish 7.0.9

Comment: GlassFish already provides JSF and JPA (EclipseLink) out the box. Did you take that into account? Faces definitely needs to be removed or at least marked `provided`. Hibernate can also be removed when you use **only** `jakarta.persistence` classes from JPA. What exactly is the reason you want to use Hibernate instead of EclipseLink?

Comment: use hibernate envers for that reason

Answer (score 0):

You are already depending on

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>10.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Which includes JPA, you should use JPA classes instead of Hibernate and your problem will be solved.

Comment: True, but more than often Tomcat users use that dependency without really understanding what it does. Look at the Faces dependency. It's surprisingly also non-provided. So most likely the target runtime actually doesn't provide Faces out the box. And then usually also not JPA. I.e. it's actually not a real Jakarta EE runtime. It's better to ask first which server exactly the OP is using instead of assuming that the OP is actually using real Jakarta EE. Generally the exact server make/version is deductible from the stack trace but the OP also neglected to post that.

Comment: seeing jakarta.platform provided i assumed it was a jakarta compatible runtime but you are right i shouldn't have assumed that.

Comment: The interesting thing is that it only gives an error on the variable @Version.

Comment: use https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.1/apidocs/jakarta.persistence/jakarta/persistence/version change import of the version to jakarta.persistence

Comment: I did what you said but the result is the same and I even did a version upgrade.   @Version
    @Column(name = "VERSION")
    private Long version;
However, I noticed that when the server starts up, it gives an error like this. ERROR org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetadataContext - HHH015007: Illegal argument on static metamodel field injection : org.hibernate.envers.DefaultRevisionEntity_#class_; expected type :  org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.EntityTypeImpl; encountered type : jakarta.persistence.metamodel.MappedSuperclassType]]

Comment: change all Hibernate dependencies to jakarta dependencies use these ones https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/10/apidocs/ instead.

like jakarta.persistence.Entity and so on.

Comment: . also remove 
these two from your pom they unnecessary 

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
   <artifactId>jakarta.faces</artifactId>
   <version>4.0.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>6.4.3.Final</version>
   <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>

Comment: I don't understand why I would remove hibernate

Comment: Because you are already depending on jakarta ee api which includes jpa which is implented by EclipseLink in Glassfish you are using. EclipseLink provides same benefits Hibernate does because they implement same api JPA in specific so there is no reason depending on Hibernate,  you are creating a dependency problem for yourself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256869/discussion-between-ebuzer-taha-kanat-and-omer-faruk-kurt).